# Console doesn't output defined variable

Tags: javascript

The code works prefectly on the webpage.

```js
var clock = document.getElementById('current-time');
  
  var d = new Date();
  
 clock.innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
```

When I want to check the value in console it outputs an error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined
>      at :1:1

Two notes:

1. I'm using 'use strict';  mode
2. It's inside document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {...

Can any of these cause problem?

Comment: Why not show us all the code including HTML?

Comment: And with HTML, at least provide a working snippet please

Comment: Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); the code you've posted so far works fine...

Comment: Showing code that works and asking for help on other code that you didn't show... How exactly do you expect anyone to help?

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to check the value in console it outputs an error

It sounds like you want to check the value in the developer console (the error location at `1:1` indicates that).

In this case that variable isn't defined, because the developer console only sees the global scope. It's like doing this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // declare variable in inner scope
  var foo = 'bar';
});

console.log(foo); // can't see the inner scope
```

What you could do (only for debugging!):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // declare variable in inner scope, but also create a global one
  var foo = window.foo = 'bar';
});

console.log(foo); // print the global 'foo'
```

(Obviously, this does not work, because the `DOMContentLoaded` event is not fired in the snippet.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access a variable in console which is in block level scope.

For your information you can't access a variable in browser console if that variable is in function level scope or in a callback. You can access variables in console if that variable is global